# Android:how to retrieve youtube search results and their video id?

Tags: android, youtube

I think my question is quite clear itself,also i want to play it in my own video player,and not in the video player which comes with the android...hence the below code won't solve my problem.I just don't know how to query on youtube by a word.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
intent.putExtra("query", "Android");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to play youtube videos through your own player then your probably going to have to use HTTP Requests and look through this at some point.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol

This way you can parse responses from the API and get links directly to the video you want depending on search requests, if thats a planned feature of your app.

Comment: well darryl i am using a github project which plays video if the video id is supplied, i just don't know how i can create video ids

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [official YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)